# How do I install dos.h in ubuntu

Tags: c, header-files

I got this message when I compiled a C program

"fatal error: dos.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated."

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The problem is that the code you're compiling isn't meant to be run under Linux, not that `dos.h` is missing.

Comment: You don't. It's like asking how do I make my gasoline car take diesel fuel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can't do that, because from the sound of it, "dos.h" is specific to MS-DOS.